# How to export excel file from query result in Laravel Controller(Laravel latest version)?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, model, controller

Laravel experts.
Nice to meet you.
I gain the result of array type from query run.
Originally, I tried to use Excel::create function(). But the result was failed in New version.
So, I'm trying to export this datas in Controller as Excel.

If you have a experience in this field, Please help me.

Comment: Are you saying that Excel::create used to work, but after upgrading Laravel it no longer does?

Comment: Yes, Perhaps. It doen't use in latest version.

Comment: 1st it is good to check for break changes at the package which you have upgraded.
2nd in SO it is good to show your code and then to tell us about the problem.. How to help you when we don't know neither your laravel/excel versions or what code you have written ?